# Find user role - Identity framework

Tags: c#

how do you find user role within the Master page?
I have tried the following;

```
        var user = Session["UserRole"];     

        if (user.role.Any(u => admin.Contains(u.Role.Name)))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Admin.aspx");
        }
```

I'm trying to find user role within the Master page, but I cannot set the properties

i.e. Model.AspNetRole userrole { get; set; }

Recieving error "The name get does not exist in current context"

Full code below, is this the best way to find user role?

```
 public void RedirectClickCall(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Model.AspNetRole userrole { get; set; }

        string loginID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

        using ( dbcontext = new ())
        {

            userrole = (from r in dbcontext.AspNetRoles

                        where r == loginID

                        select r).FirstOrDefault();         
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using asp.net default identity database?

Comment: Yes using Identity database

Comment: Try Roles.GetRolesForUser();